Dimension of group scheme
I am new to algebraic geometry and reading group schemes and their representations from Jantzen’s book. My question id the following:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ be a field. Then there exists a group scheme $\mathbf{G}$ corresponding to $G$ via the equivalence of categories category of finite algebraic $k$-groups and category of finite dimensional cocommutative Hopf algebras over $k$. Then what we can say about the dimension of the group scheme $\mathbf{G}$? Does it equal  the dimension of the Hopf algebra?

If cardinality of $G$ is $n$ then the dimension of the Hopf algebra $kG$ is $n$. So does the dimension of $\mathbf{G}$ equal $n$?

If the Hopf algebra is of finite dimension the group scheme has dimension 0.

@JonathanWise Thanks for your comment. Can you tell the reason? And what happens for infinite groups?

Re, this question is probably more suited for MSE.  As it is, you'll want to start with the definition of the dimension of a scheme.  In terms of what happens if $G$ is infinite, I think Jantzen wants to restrict to schemes of finite type over $k$, though I'm not certain.
